# Remove Sass comments on a per-file basis?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I want to remove the comments that SASS generates in the CSS files for only one file whileallowing for the rest of my CSS files to have these comments. Is there a way to do this? All I know if is the `line_comments = false` option in the config.rb but that disables them for the whole projet.

Comment: Have you considered using inline style comments (`//this is a comment`) for comments that should not be a part of the compiled CSS and traditional block style comments (`/* this is also a comment */`) for comments that are?

Comment: The comments that I'm referring to are the ones that automatically generated by SASS. These aren't comments that I'm adding myself.

Comment: All production compiled CSS should be minified with no Sass comments. That's a given. I'm curious why you want to disable them for development.

Comment: I'm converting an existing file (we'll call it example.css) to SASS that is linked to a large number of files. Due to time constraints and other reasons, switching all of the existing files that call example.css to example-min.css is not optimal at this moment. If I could generate an example.css from example.scss without all of the comments that come with SASS compilation, that would be great. If you know how to do so, by all means, please answer the question! Thanks!

Comment: Solution: don't rename the file to `*-min.css`. Just compile the Sass—minified—to `example.css` in the same place that the other files reference it. For development, the comments don't matter. For production, all of your stylesheets should be minified with comments turned off.

Answer (score 4):

I really believe the solution you think you want is not what you actually want. It's adding a layer of complexity.

Comments, by definition, don't affect how your CSS renders. They don't affect "`example.sass`/`example.css`" and they don't affect any of your other stylesheets. During development you have them turned on to help you, but they aren't changing how anything renders.

For production there should be no comments, and everything should be minified.

So, when you're developing set your `config.rb`

```
output_style   = :expanded
environment    = :development
```

And when you're ready to go live:

```
output_style   = :compressed
environment    = :production
```

Changing the `output_style` and `environment` don't change the directory or the filenames, they just remove the comments and take out extraneous spaces.

During development your `example.css` will be a little longer, but if it's cached and you're not changing it, it won't take any longer to compile, and since you're removing the comments and minifying for production your users will get the fastest download times.

Comment: This is an all or nothing solution. What I'm looking for is something that allows for me to pick and choose, which it appears Sass won't let me do.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is *why* you want to pick and choose, and even if you could, really think about if it's worth any extra work.

Comment: Although the information you've supplied is seemingly accurate, this does not actually answer the question; it just denies the premise of the question and answers a different one, which is not particularly helpful. If you believe what the OP is asking for is impossible or impractical, then I think it would be better to say so and give reasoning to justify that.